# Proof request : $\delta'(x) = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\delta(x+2a) - \delta(x-a)}{a}$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta

How would one prove the following property for the dirac $\delta$ function ?

$$\delta'(x) = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\delta(x+2a) - \delta(x-a)}{a}$$

where $\delta$ is the famous function :
$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} +\infty & x=0, \\ 0 & x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: What is the delta function?

Comment: should that be taken in the sens of distributions?

Comment: @GuyFsone Yes !

Comment: @Wen the Dirac Delta function : $$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} +\infty & x=0, \\ 0 & x \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Rebellos ***Everything*** needs clarification if someone asks for it.  Different people have different contexts and different knowledge.

Comment: I'm not really good at distributions, but it looks more like $3\delta'(x)$ than $\delta '(x)$. May it happen to be a typo?

Comment: @lisyarus Me neither, but it was copied from a hand-textbook of exercises from our professor. Maybe it could be !

Comment: @Rebellos how do you define $\delta'$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u$ be a smooth function with compact support and let the sequence of $(T_a)_a$distribution  with 
$$T_a  = \frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x-a)}{a}$$

Then,

$$ \left(  T_a,u\right)  = \left(  \frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x-a)}{a}, u\right)  =  \frac{u(x+2a)-u(x-a)}{a} \\= 2\frac{u(x+2a)-u(x)}{2a}+\frac{u(x-a)-u(x)}{-a}\to 3u'(x)= -3(\delta'(x), u)$$

That $T_a\to -3\delta'(x)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $3u'(0)$? The last line seems to reduce to $2u'(0) {\color{red}+} u'(0)$, and not to $2u'(0) {\color{red}-} u'(0)$

Comment: @lisyarus Thanks I have correct my computation

Comment: I agree with the result but not with the computation : one should write $\left(  T_a,u\right)  = \left(  \frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x-a)}{a}, u\right)  =  \frac{u(-2a)-u(a)}{a} \\= -2\frac{u(-2a)-u(0)}{-2a}+\frac{u(0)-u(a)}{a}\to -3u'(0)= -3(\delta', u)$